# What's the use of route_options in Active Admin

Tags: routes, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-6

What's the exact use of active admin method route_options as

```
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.route_options = { path: '/admin', subdomain: 'admin' }
end
```

Using rails 6, how we can use it to make a subdomain 'admin' to use all active_admin things? like

http://admin.localhost:3000/admin ?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the route_options when we would like to mount the namespace to a subdomain instead of path:

Case1-

```
    config.namespace :admin do |admin|
      admin.route_options = { path: '', subdomain: 'admin' }
    end
```

what its actually do is, for namespace admin replace the subdomain with path ''

```
   HELPER                  PATH                controller#action
   admin_admin_users_path  /admin/admin_users   admin/admin_users#index
```

Behaviour for this config route_options-

```
   HELPER                   PATH               controller#action 
   admin_admin_users_path  /admin_users  admin/admin_users#index(:subdomain=>”admin”)
```

Case2-

```
  config.namespace :admin do |admin|
     admin.route_options = { path: '/admin ', subdomain: 'admin' }
  end
```

In this case, behaves the same as default behaviour(default behaviour means either we use this or not routes form like this for namespace admin with path '/admin').

```
  HELPER                  PATH                 controller#action
  admin_admin_users_path  /**admin**/admin_users   admin/admin_users#index
                         (subdomain)
```

Case 3-
Change namespace-

```
  config.namespace :super do |admin|
     admin.route_options = { path: '', subdomain: 'admin' }
  end
```

Behaviour-

```
  HELPER                  PATH                 controller#action
  super_users_path        /users               super/users#index(:subdomain=>”admin”)
```